# Active Directory and Express/Node

Tags: node.js, express, active-directory, windows-authentication

I would like to use Active Directory with a REST API Express backend: users would fill out a username and login form on the client side, and get authenticated with their Active Directory credentials, through the backend. Then, based on their user groups, they would see certain information. I have tried the node package [passport-windowsauth](https://github.com/auth0/passport-windowsauth), but I am not able to authenticate, possibly because I don't know what the **bindDN** or **bindCredentials** are. I have also tried [node-sspi](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sspi), and had better luck with this, but the issue with this is that it's only server-side, and as far as I can tell, I can't create a form that would then allow the user to authenticate from the client side. I am hosting this site on IIS, and using iisnode for the backend. How can I can achieve this Active Directory authentication with Node/Express server-side and a client-side login form, or in other words, not a .NET application?

Comment: bindDN = Distinguished Names https://ldap.com/ldap-dns-and-rdns/, bindCredentials = Password

Comment: I also can recommend you the ldapjs module: http://ldapjs.org/client.html

Comment: @marcel.js how would the bindDN be found based on the username from a form?

Comment: An example would be this: 'uid=john.doe,ou=People,dc=example,dc=com'. Take a look at this: https://ldap.com/ldap-dns-and-rdns/

Comment: @marcel.js I have read the article you linked to, and also tried ldapjs previously. I entered in my information that should work with binddn but it is not authenticating.

Comment: you have to know how your active directory is set up (dc, ou's, ...)
and if you think you have the right dn you can test it with a hardcoded dn which should work and look if and what error you get.

Comment: Is there any way to figure out what my BindDN is from the command prompt or anything?

Answer (score 0):

Active Directory (AD) authentication is accomplished by binding to the Active Directory with credentials (not the credentials from the User form) supplied by your AD engineers. After binding, AD is searched for matching credentials (from the User form).

Basically you need to talk to your AD engineers about what you should use.

Then you need a `/login/` route the user form sends to, the route accomplishes the login (AD bind, authentication) and returns to the client.

A simpler workaround can be to bind to AD with the credentials entered into the login form - a successful bind means the user is logged in. I would, again, talk to your AD engineers about how they prefer this to be done. I've run into problems in the past where it's taken a long time to authenticate users after binding so we used this as a workaround.

You might ask if your AD already has single-sign-on options - maybe they use Shiboleth or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

You should try that package : https://www.npmjs.com/package/ad I'm not sure it will meet your requirements, but it's a very easy t work with Active Directory in a node/express back end.

Comment: The library hasn't been updated in 2 years. I won't recommend using it.